# find and update one field in array of subdoc mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new in mongodb and mongoose. i'm using node js, and i want to find and update specific field in one of array in sub document.
here is my data structure :

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
comment: [
  {
    name: String,
    value: String
  }
],
createdAt: Date,
updateAt: Date
})
```

this is my data example :

```
{ 
   _id : 12,
   title : 'some article here...',
   comment : [{
                _id : 1,
                name : 'joe',
                value : 'wow that fantastic...'
             },{
                _id : 2,
                name : 'rocky',
                value : 'really... thats insane...'                    
             },{
                _id : 3,
                name : 'jane',
                value : 'i think its impossible to do...'                  
             }],
   createdAt : 2016-04-14 04:50:54.760Z,
   updatedAt : 2016-04-14 04:50:54.760Z
}
```

i need to update comment which have _id : 2, i want to change the value become 'what???'. i try to update with :

```
Post.findOne({'_id': 12, 'comment._id': 2}, {_id: 0, 'comment.$': 1}, function (err, cb) {
  cb.comment.value = 'what???'
  cb.save()
})
```

but it failed... so, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Answer (score 2):

you can use `findOneAndUpdate` and positional operator `$` to update specific comment value

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": 12, "comment._id": 2},
         {
           $set: {
                "comment.$.value ": "New value set here"
            }
         },
         { new: true } // return updated post
        ).exec(function(error, post) {
            if(error) {
                return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Update failed!'});
            }

            return res.status(200).send(post);
        });
```

Comment: it return no error. but my data doesn't change at all in mongo. in my database, comment is array of subdocs. maybe need number of array to edit that comment.

Comment: You should add {new : true} after updating the data to get the updated document

Answer (score 0):

It will work for array updation in mongodb using mongoose

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
            { id: 12,comment_id:2 },
            { $push: { comment:"new comment" } }
          )
```